# Using clojure in android

Tags: android, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have written a clojure program that performs data manipulations of some complexity.

I would like to bring this functionality to my phone.

As an alternative to having to reimplement the whole code in java, I thought it would be nice to use clojure to generate a library to be called from Java. This would also prevent me from having to keep two versions of the same functionality in sync during the development process.

The general idea:

The java-part of the app passes a JSON-String to Clojure; The clojure-part performs the data manipulations in and then returns a JSON-String back to java.

**Question: Is this possible? If so: How?**

Edit: Note that the question is not about building a whole android app in clojure but rather about exposing clojure functions to an **existing** java/android app.

Comment: I don't think you've done sufficient research prior to asking you question.  A routine Google search for "using clojure library on an android phone" yields several useful results.

Comment: a good overview and tutorial here: http://clojure-android.info/
which covers using the lein-droid leiningen plugin.

Comment: Thank you; I had a look at the respective libraries but I found only information on how to build an android app in clojure. Instead I would like to expose some functions written in clojure to an existing java/android project. Could you provide me with a link on this topic?

Comment: Garlef, do you mean that you want to know how to bundle some Clojure functions into a library that can be called from a Java app running on Android?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out: Use gen-class and compile the project with "lein uberjar" and ":aot :all" in the project.clj. Then add the .jar as a library to the android project. It will provide the funcionality as a class.